# Can I change state of mapping variable in deployed contract from another contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, solidity-0.6.x

I am calling addCoin and subCoin function of my **AirToken contract** and **Hotel contract**.

**This is function defination of addCoin and subCoin in AirToken contract and Hotel contract**

```
function addCoin(address addr, uint256 amount) public
    {
        balances[addr] += amount;
    }

    function subCoin(address addr, uint256 amount) public
    {
        balances[addr] -= amount;
    }
```

Below lines are my **loyalty Contract** exchange function where I am calling **addCoin** and **subCoin**

```
(bool success1,bytes memory returnData1)= fromContractAddress.call(abi.encodePacked(bytes20(keccak256("subCoin(address,uint256)")),tokenOwner,exchangeAmount));
        require(success1);
(bool success2,bytes memory returnData2)= toContractAddress.call(abi.encodePacked(bytes20(keccak256("addCoin(address,uint256)")),tokenOwner,exchangeAmount));
        require(success2);
```

These lines are not giving any error but balances are not updated that should happen if **addCoin** and **subCoin** have executed succesfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash of your function is:

```
bytes32 hash = keccak256("subCoin(address,uint256)");
```

Which means that your function-selector is:

```
bytes4 selector = bytes4(uint256(hash) >> 224);
```

So I would try to replace this:

```
abi.encodePacked(bytes20(hash), tokenOwner, exchangeAmount)
```

With this:

```
abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, tokenOwner, exchangeAmount)
```

Comment: It worked with  some little modification.    In selector instead of "bytes4(uint256(hash >> 224)) " I replaced it with "bytes4(hash)"

Comment: @PardeepThakur: Yes, it's the same. Both should work.

Comment: I don't know but **"bytes4(uint256(hash >> 224))"** was not working.  It was giving me error **"uint256 cannot be explicitly converted to bytes4"**

Comment: @PardeepThakur: Sorry, it should have been `uint256(hash) >> 224`, not `uint256(hash >> 224)`. I'll fix it.